# Remove dates with no data in SSRS 2016 time chart (Daily chart)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm wondering if dates with zero/null values can be disregarded in the time chart. Data points in line charts are showcasing down trends for dates with no data, since SSRS are using calendar dates (Mostly happens in weekends).

Are there any solutions or workarounds? Maybe using Parameters?

[image]

Comment: What properties are you using on your horizontal axis? I just created a simple line chart with a Scalar Axis type and passed in a bunch of dates an numbers. Where there is no value the data point is missing and the line connects the previous and next datapoints as expected.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe if you omit the weekend data from your Target, LCL and UCL data (looks like its hardcoded), it will close the gaps.

Comment: Just note that I'm using SSRS 2016 Mobile report publisher. Even If I omit the weekend data, Target, LCL and UCL will drop as well.